# cfprefsd using > 90% CPU - any way to find out what program is using it?

Tags: macos, cpu, osx-el-capitan

In the last few weeks I've noticed my macbookpro (mid-2014, core i7, retina 16Gb RAM, el capitan patched to latest) running quite hot and looking at the CPU usage it seems it's cfprefsd that's doing the damage with over 90%.

I'm aware cfprefsd is just covering up for some other process but I don't know how to go about finding out. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I've also noticed this. Some threads from apple.com https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7254706?start=0&tstart=0
and https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7339944

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible that when we upgrade from Yosemite to El Capitan, our bluetooth settings are backed up and are read by the system.

I found that this was the file that had a few duplicates:
`/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist`

sudo removing all these files then doing a PRAM and SMC reset immediately worked for me!

PRAM and SMC reset :
Shut down your Mac, press the power button, and as soon as you hear the startup chime, hold down <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

Comment: I just nuked the plist files and rebooted and so far so good. It's hardly a proper fix but it works so it'll do.

Comment: Actually, it didn't really stay fixed. When it becomes an issue I can just disable and re-enable bluetooth but this still feels like a "hack" and not terribly scientific.

Answer (score 10):

This "fixed" it for me:

I noticed cfprefsd was hammering the disk - so I used [fs_usage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/fs_usage.1.html) to track what it was writing:

1. Open *Activity Moniter*, get the *PID* of *cfprefsd*
2. Open *Terminal*, `sudo fs_usage pid <PID>`.

   I saw my bluetooth preferences file was getting smashed.
3. So I **disabled bluetooth** and *cfprefsd*.

   CPU usage dropped instantly to negligible levels.

I realise this is not fixing the root problem, but this made my previously unusable macbook air usable again, so I thought others might appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

OK, I just saw the same symptoms on a recently updated MacBook Pro 13" (2015 edition so the latest hardware).  I updated to El Capitan and sometime soon after started noticing the slowness issue.  I had noticed a cfprefs process hogging CPU but not enough to be causing the severe performance issues I was seeing (keyboard non responsive, etc.)

Turning off bluetooth indeed solved the problem IMMEDIATELY so I think you've found your link.  Instead of leaving it off I turned it back on, deleted the one device profile that was connected (an external trackpad) and then re-paired.  So far so good; not sure what the "actual" issue was but if this resolves it long-term then I think it's a reasonable workaround.

Answer (score 0):

The same happened to me just now. Turned of Bluetooth completely and then the process disappeared.

Running MacBook with El Capitan and latest updates.